# Reference other cells based on value from dropdown list

Tags: excel, validation, dropdown

I have a sheet in which I store information about many variables (call this the reference sheet). I then have another sheet where I want to populate a column based on IDs from this other sheet, and then reference the other columns in the sheet depending on which ID is selected (either directly by pulling the values in - this may be easiest, or indirectly by using the values in a formula).

Example:

Reference Sheet:

[image: Reference Sheet]

What I'd like to create:

[image: Main Sheet]

Where the id "C" was created using Data Validation from the Reference Sheet ID column. What I want is for Var1 - Var3 to be created by referring to the row in the reference sheet corresponding to "C". Alternatively, a calculation (in this case it's the sum of var 1 + var 2 divided by var 3) based on these values could be done in this sheet. Note: for this example, I just copied the output I want - but I do not know how to create this dynamically (which is my question).

Is this something that is possible in Excel? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: You already done it. So, what is the question?

Comment: @Harun24HR I did this manually - I haven't actually done anything, but showed the output I want. I will make this more explicit in the question.

Comment: @amquack will the columns Var 1, var 2 etc... always be the same name and in the same order on both sheets? or do you want to match Row "C" AND Column "Var 1" dynamically?

Comment: @Dave I had imagined that the easiest thing would be to have var1, var2 etc match the other sheet, so this is why I include it. In practice, I'd likely hide these columns - since what I want is to know how to create a calculation like that above. That said, it hadn't crossed my mind that matching Row C and column Var1 dynamically was a possibility. It's not necessary for my current project, but it does seem very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the reference sheet is called `sheet1`, you can put this formula in the other sheet (in cell B2): `=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$6,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6,0),MATCH(B$1,Sheet1!$B$1:$D$1,0))`. Use the fill handle to copy the formula to the cells to the right (until D2).

And this formula in cell E2: `=(B2+C2)/D2`.

[image]

Comment: In the formula, I have made it that the columns will match as well, so make sure that they do...